# console app Entity Framework db.savechanges not saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I've been staring at this until I can't see straight.  I've got a console app that i'm using to test the logic out before I convert it to a service.   The same code works fine when fired from the web app The student object gets filled fine and it isn't throwing any errors but when it never saves to the database.   any insight on what the heck I'm missing?

my app.config file has the connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DatabaseContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Development.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  <add name="DevelopmentEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Development.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    //fill student object and add to list
    Student s = new Student();
    s.SID = dr[0].ToString();
    s.FirstName = dr[1].ToString();
    s.LastName = dr[2].ToString();
    if (sctType == "TRAD")
    { s.Type = Convert.ToInt32(UniversityGateway.Data.Models.StudentType.Traditional); }
    else
    { s.Type = Convert.ToInt32(UniversityGateway.Data.Models.StudentType.AGS); }
    s.Email = dr[5].ToString();
    s.Address = new Address
    {
         Street = dr[6].ToString(),
        City = dr[9].ToString(),
        State = dr[10].ToString(),
        Zip = dr[11].ToString(),
    };
    s.UserActive = "Y";
    s.Status = Convert.ToInt32(UniversityGateway.Data.Models.StudentStatus.Pending);
    s.Password = "kHPrSps3JnTkmky7PakBZg==Wdc9Qgcz39p+s6+fqk/nUw==";
    students.Add(s);
    using (var db = new UniversityGateway.Data.DatabaseContext())
    {
        db.Students.Add(s);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any transaction scope ?

Comment: if you're talking about the transactionscope class, no.

Comment: Why you have two connection strings for the same database?

Comment: So the app knows how to connect to the databasecontext.

Comment: May be there is a exception in service side .Did you try to debug your service ?.Any way you don't have to have two connection strings for one db context(Or on DB).can you post your db context code. Are you using code fist or model first?

Comment: I'm not running it as a service yet.  just a console app in debug mode.  not throwing any errors, just not saving to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was saving the object.  Just to a different database than what is specified in the connect string.    Got another question on SO as to how in the heck to fix that.